# electrical switch wiring question

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch, smart-switch

I’m attempting to replace both of the switches in this box with Amazon basics smart switches, but I haven’t really encountered something like this before. Note the ground wire connected to one switched pole on the switch!

Attempting to connect the new switches in the config shown in the pic just immediately blows the breaker.

Wiring the switches in the way that seems intuitively correct results in only the switch on the right working. When I say intuitively, I mean splitting the bundle of white wires and connecting them to each switch, the black wires to each switch, etc.

No matter what I do here, best case I’m only getting that switch on the right to work. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Add pictures of how the lights are wired also, so we can see if this will be simple or complicated.

Comment: I’ll see if I can get some pics in a bit. I don’t think there is anything too out of the ordinary there though. Whatever is going on here was that way for all 14 years that we’ve been in the house though…

Comment: Just a statement...That is the most bizarre wiring I have ever seen.  I understand the black relay to power both switches, but the ground connected too!!!!

Answer (score 4):

Anytime you see ground connected to neutral or live you have big problem.

Ground wires can/must only be connected to other ground wires and/or metal junction/switch/outlet boxes.

You have a rewiring job ahead of you now.  Should turn off the breaker for that circuit till it is fixed.

Hopefully they just goofed up a simple switch loop job and used ground instead of a white wire.  It looks like the switch on the right controls two lights, one with the black wire and one with the ground wire.

The black wire on the bottom screw should be your hot/live wire from the panel and also goes somewhere else.

Comment: Where are you seeing the ground connected to neutral or hot?

Comment: Using ground for neutral is a common(not good) hack if neutral wire is broken.  Using ground for hot is just bad.  OP seems to have the bad one.  OP's picture shows a bare wire connected to the switch hot screw of the switch.  Bare wire can only be used for ground.  Here it is used as hot(switched hot), I call all bare wire ground.

Comment: Oh, yep, I missed that ground entirely.  Bad!

Comment: Curiosity got the better of me over lunch (I work from home). I did a bit more digging. I can’t seem to add another image, but I found that all the ground wires are connected deeper in the box, so it can’t be that they used a ground to supply power. After discovering this, I removed the smart switches and reconnected the original switches as they were, except for the grounds. This time I connected the ground wires where they belong: on the green screw of each switch… and everything works.

Comment: All I can make of this is some kind of error on the part of the last guy to come along (connecting the ground to the wrong pole of the switch). How it still worked is beyond me…

Comment: There is something very wrong here.  If that bare ground was connected to the other grounds, then that breaker should have tripped in less than a second you turned on the switch.  The only way for the breaker not to trip was if that bare wire was connected to a light and hope all the boxes were plastic.  I would suspect your whole electric system until checked.  One mistake like this, usually means there can be others.